# Wicd tray icon fails to appear in system notification area even though in dconf>desktop>unity>panel/whitelist

Tags: unity, 11.10, system-tray, wicd

I'm trying to get the Wicd (replacement for non-functional Network Manager) icon to show up in my laptop's systray/notification area.  The solution that worked for 11.04 Ubuntu/Unity does not work for 11.10 Ubuntu/Unity.

Apparently the whitelist is ignored, as Skype shows up in the systray but is not in the whitelist.

This is a showstopper for Ubuntu on this laptop.

Update:  I am running 3d and the whitelist is ignored.

Comment: Works fine here in both 11.10 & 12.04 - are you sure you're using unity-3d? For unity-2d to get systray icons you may need to use 'all' instead of specific whitelist entries.(depends on unity-2d version. If on unity 3d run this command  & edit in the results exactly as shown. gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel  systray-whitelist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not fixable and no workaround.

Only way out is to dump unity and go to Gnome classic.

See the [bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/761409)

Update:  Now marked "Fix released" but still doesn't work.

Comment: I have upgraded the laptop to 12.04 LTS, dropped Wicd and am now using Network Manager.  I must say 12.04 Gnome Classic is great!