# Enable WICD System-Tray Icon - Unity 15.04

Tags: unity, 15.04, icons, system-tray, wicd

I've installed wicd and wicd-gtk in Unity - Ubuntu 15.04. The icon for the application does not show up in the system tray.

I've looked over the following questions, which do not solve my issue:

[WICD system tray icon doesn't show up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580964/wicd-system-tray-icon-doesnt-show-up)

[How do I get the Wicd manager to appear in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85688/how-do-i-get-the-wicd-manager-to-appear-in-the-system-tray)

[Wicd tray icon fails to appear in system notification area even though in dconf>desktop>unity>panel/whitelist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96033/wicd-tray-icon-fails-to-appear-in-system-notification-area-even-though-in-dconf)

[WICD tray icon doesn't show](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69005/wicd-tray-icon-doesnt-show)

[How do I get the Wicd manager to appear in the system tray?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85688/how-do-i-get-the-wicd-manager-to-appear-in-the-system-tray)

I still have the issue. Panel does not exist in the DConf for Unity. Various external unity hacks found on these pages didn't work either. Also, various answers relate to older version of Ubuntu, while I'm running 15.04.

Comment: to bad 15.04 is EOL because I found a version for vivid: ppa:gurqn/systray-vivid